# Capybara and Ajax test not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, capybara

I submit a form with ajax. When there are errors on the form submission the form is rendered again using ajax, jquery.

I am trying to test this behavior with Capybara and Rspec as follows:

describe "board creation failure", :type => :request do

```
      it "should not create a birthday board" do
        Capybara.default_wait_time = 5
            lambda do
              visit root_path
              fill_in "Name",      :with => ""
              select('1967', :from => "board_birthday_1i" )
              select('October',   :from => "board_birthday_2i" )
              select('30',   :from => "board_birthday_3i" )
              click_button("Start the surprise")
              page.should have_selector('div#error_explanation')
              page.find_field('Name').value
            end.should_not change(Board, :count)
      end
    end
```

The results are as follows:

```
  Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('div#error_explanation')
       expected following output to contain a <div#error_explanation/> tag:
```

However I do in fact have an error_explanation div on the page.

Why does this test fail?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you adding somewhere :js => true option so the ajax is executed?

Comment: I have both Capybara and webrat in my gem file. I think there is a conflict between webrat and capybara that is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by waiting few seconds until the response arrive.

Add `sleep(3)` before

```
page.should have_selector('div#error_explanation')
```

line and test again.
This might help.